# svg blur filter to create outer glow not working

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm struggling to create an outer glow on an svg `<rect>` element.  I have a top `<rect>` that's white, and below it, I want to apply a `<feGaussianBlur>` to a blue `<rect>` so that the top white `<rect>` has the appearance that it is glowing blue.  I've been unable to get the blur to render. What am I missing?

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="takeaway" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 432 2663.8" xml:space="preserve">      
  <style><![CDATA[
     .card {fill:#fff;}
     .card_glowSource{fill:#3361bd;filter:url(#cardGlowSource);}
    ]]></style>
  <defs>
     <filter id="cardGlowSouce" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="140">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic"/>
     </filter>     
</defs>
  <g id="glowRect" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,30,190)">
    <rect class="card_glowSource" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="140" rx="5" ry="5"/> 
 <rect class="card" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="140" rx="5" ry="5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. There's a typo in your filter name. "cardGlowSouce" should be "cardGlowSource".
2. You will need to remove the x, y, width and height attributes from your `<filter>` element if you want the filter to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two shapes, a filter can handle blur, recoloring the blur, and putting the original shape on top of the blur.

As paul notes, you have a typo, and also you are setting the filter region to the same size as the shape - which means that you are clipping your blur to your shape - so... no glow outside your shape.

Below is an example of a filter that does what you want in a more elegant way.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="takeaway" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 432 2663.8" xml:space="preserve">      
  <style><![CDATA[
     .card {fill:#fff;filter:url(#cardGlow);}
    ]]></style>
  <defs>
     <filter id="cardGlow" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic"/>
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .12 
                                               0 0 0 0 .23 
                                               0 0 0 0 .75 
                                               0 0 0 1 0"/>
     <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
     </filter>     
</defs>
  <g id="glowRect" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,30,190)"> 
 <rect class="card" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="140" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: rx and ry create rounded `<rect>` elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement

Comment: This is a really elegant solution.  Thank you.  There's some good reading here about combining filters: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/tutorials/smarter_svg_filters

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing... Thanks for the correction Robert.